# Are parodied scenes in the Monogatari anime described in the light novel?

Tags: monogatari-series

In many scenes of *Monogatari* series, sometimes a character's art style changes because they were acting like other anime characters. Examples are given in the images below.

[image: img1]
[image: img2]
[image: img3]
[image: img4]

Are these scenes described in the original source (light novel) when their faces changed into other anime/manga characters? For example, when Araragi (left-bottom image) said:

> I didn't fail to pay it!

he is parodying *[Kaiji](http://kaiji.wikia.com/wiki/Kaiji_Itou)*'s face from the anime *[Kaiji: Ultimate Survivor](https://myanimelist.net/anime/3002/Gyakkyou_Burai_Kaiji__Ultimate_Survivor)*:

[image: Kaiji Itou]

Then does the light novel have a passage like this (for example):

> "I didn't fail to pay it", while my face turned into Kaiji's serious look.

or were these scenes originally made just for the anime version?

---

The reason why I think about this is that there is a scene in *No Game No Life* that matches between the anime and light novel like below:

> **"I refuse!" Blurting out these words caused her eyes to widen in response.**
>
> "Could you...... tell me your reason?"
>
> "Hehe, that's because....." Sora hugged his little sister who was watching with an expression that could not be discerned.
>
> "One of our most favoritethings for 『 』 is—"
>
> **"Standing in a position where the opponent has an advantage and denying it with a 'NO' !"**
>
> Shiro combined together. Originally unclear of the plot, Steph and Kurami could not arrange this reasoning properly. Only looking at the excited siblings while feeling stunned.
>
> **"Wahaha! 'I always wanted to try and say the number four lines[19] ' —and I really said it out!"**
>
> ".......Nii, nice, good job."

It's similar to the anime version. They also made this scene which is described in the light novel. (Sora said a phrase which originally came from *[Kishibe Rohan](http://jojo.wikia.com/wiki/Rohan_Kishibe)*'s statement, a side character of *[Jojo's Bizarre Adventure: Diamond Is Unbreakable](http://jojo.wikia.com/wiki/Diamond_Is_Unbreakable)*.

[image]
[image]

Comment: some of the parody is original to anime and some don't, as in it was also in light novel, although I'm not sure which